# How to make div inside a absolute parent stick to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a chat window which should animate open on click like following:

[image]

The chat window should be absolute to the viewport so I can move it in hindsight anywhere on the browser window. But I need to stick some elements like the input element and some icons inside the chat window to the bottom so I can animate the chat to open while these elements stay in place.

Would be nice if someone could help me out!

My html looks sort of this:

```html
<div id="chat">
  <svg id="openCloseWindow" height="28px" width="28px" viewbox="0 0 28 28"></svg>
  <div id"IshouldStickToTheBottomOfTheChatWindow">
    <svg id="chatEmote" height="28px" width="28px" viewbox="0 0 28 28"></svg>
    <input id="messageBar" type="text" placeholder="message" name="message">
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's really straightforward, using a `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`. See the below snippet in its **full screen**:

```css
.chat {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.chat span {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.chat.open {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat" onclick="this.classList.toggle('open');">
  <span>Click Me!</span>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank U, but my actual question is how i stick an element to the bottom of the chat (in your example the text) while having a absolute chat position.

Comment: @JGastager You can have another div that has `position: absolute` inside the `div` with `bottom: 0` again and have things on the bottom.

Comment: @JGastager Can you check the updated answer please?

Comment: OMG, thank U! Why did I think that the child also refers to the viewport?!

Comment: @JGastager I am so glad it worked for you!  Haha, it happens sometime.

Comment: @JGastager Let me know if you need any more questions answered. Happy to help you! 